# Why is the use of reverse thrust not considered when calculating accelerate-stop distance on dry runway?

Tags: aircraft-performance

In calculating the accelerate-stop distances, what are the possible reasons why the use of reverse thrust is not taken into account on a dry runway, while it is taken into account on a wet runway? What's the rationale behind this diffentiation, when at least as I see it there's nothing that prevents the use of reverse thrust on a dry runway for an aborted takeoff?

Comment: SOP's may require the use of reverse thrust on wet/contaminated runways while not on dry runways.

Comment: Seems to be risk management. Reversers are *relatively, for an aviation technology,* unreliable, so you don't want to rely on them *too much*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your thrust reversers are operational and debris is not a concern, you're right for an in-service rejected takeoff (RTO):

> There's nothing that prevents the use of reverse thrust on a dry
>   runway for an aborted takeoff.

Most in-service RTOs utilize reverse thrust if available (see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KbAQpvBo1qg) for a dry-runway example).

However, in order to certify a transport-category airplane, one must show compliance with [14 CFR 25.109, paragraph (f)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/25.109#f), which precludes the use of thrust reversers on dry runways in calculating the accelerate-stop distance. The demonstration required by paragraph (i), therefore, cannot be conducted with reverse thrust on a dry runway. From a certification standpoint, the accelerate-stop calculation is made the way it is because that's what the regulations say. But why is the law written this way? See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_g6UswiRCF0) at about 1:12:

> The whole intent is to demonstrate [that] under [the] worst conditions you can safely stop the aircraft.

"Worst conditions" encompasses at least inoperative thrust reversers and worn brakes.